Failed to build pyHook3 during installation on windows 11
I'm trying to install pyHook3 and getting the following error:
> pip install pyHook3
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyHook3
  Using cached PyHook3-1.6.1.tar.gz (12 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyHook3
  Building wheel for pyHook3 (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyHook3 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PyHook3
      copying aa hook.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PyHook3
      copying cpyHook.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PyHook3
      copying doc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PyHook3
      copying example.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PyHook3
      copying HookManager.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PyHook3
      copying __init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PyHook3
      running build_ext
      building 'PyHook3._cpyHook' extension
      swigging cpyHook.i to cpyHook_wrap.c
      swig.exe -python -o cpyHook_wrap.c cpyHook.i
      error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
      [end of output]

**  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyHook3
Failed to build pyHook3
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pyHook3)**

What could be causing this error?
I use python 3.12.4 and Windows 11.
I also tried using pip install pyhook3 but got the same error.
